# React styles object not being applied

Tags: reactjs

I have the following functional component

```
import React from 'react';

function Note({x,y,val}) {

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <span className="note" style={{transform: `translate(${x},${y})`}}>{val}</span>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Note;
```

For some reason my inline style `` style={{transform: `translate(${x},${y})`}} `` is not being applied (my `note` class is being applied). Can anyone figure out why that is?

I try to render the Note component in the following component

```
import React from 'react';
import './Wrapper.css';
import Note from '../Note/Note';

function Wrapper() {
return (
    <div>
    <div id='0' className='wrapper'>
        <div className='string'></div>
        <div className='string'></div>
        <div className='string'></div>
        <div className='string'></div>
        <div className='string'></div>
        <div className='string'></div>
        <Note x={0} y={1} val={'f'} />
    </div>
    </div>
);
}

export default Wrapper;
```

Comment: [Translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) needs units, `translate(0, 1);` is not a valid style. What units are you trying to use?

Comment: Yeah, you are missing the units.

Comment: @RossAllen I'd add that as an answer.

Comment: You are right! Totally forgot that. I need to use percent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) needs units, `translate(0, 1);` is not a valid style. What units are you trying to use?

Add something like percent to get a valid style:

```js
<span className="note" style={{transform: `translate(${x}%, ${y}%)`}}>{val}</span>
```